# highlight hovered row in jquery plugin datatable

Tags: jquery, css, datatable

i use jquery plugin datatable to show my data,it works fine,i got my data from php using ajax,
but i got a problem when i want to highlight the hovered row when moving around the table. it do not work. but when i use the script in other table ,it works. and i pause some code in chrome console,it work fine ,i got confuse , how can i fix this.
the script here :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable({
                     "bProcessing": true,
                     "sAjaxSource": "testConn2008.php",
                     "bAutoWidth": true,
                     "aoColumns": [
                            { mData: '\u533a\u57df' } ,
                            { mData: '\u6708\u4efd' },
                            { mData: '\u7535\u8111\u7f16\u53f7' },
                            { mData: '\u7528\u6237\u518c\u53f7' } ,
                            { mData: '\u6c34\u8868\u7c7b\u578b' }
                    ]
            });
});
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {  
         $("#example tbody tr").mouseover(function() {  
                  $(this).addClass("over");  
             });  
         $("#example tbody tr").mouseout(function() {  
                  $(this).removeClass("over");  
             });   

    }); 
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
  tr.over td{  
background: #D6E8F8;  
font-weight: bold;  
}  
  </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering why you want to use jquery. Simple CSS you can achieve this.

```
#example td:hover
{
  background: #D6E8F8;  
  font-weight: bold;  
}
```